# Как добавить скрытую отладочную информацию в письмо

Tags: email, отладка, стеганография

Мне **пере**сылают письма. Трудно понять, где в коде формируется это письмо (сайтов куча), и какие данные (ID заказа, например) использовались при этом.

Мне нужно каким-то способом добавить немного скрытых "отладочных" данных, которые помогут при поиске проблем.

**Пример 1**. Пересылают письмо-уведомление, и говорят: сделай такое же уведомление еще одному сотруднику. Только по письму трудно понять, где это вообще в коде, на каком сайте. Скрытое поле "номер тикета" помогло бы справиться быстрее.

**Пример 2**. Высылаются однотипные письма "к вам выехала машина", но наш внутренний ID в эти письма в явном виде нельзя указывать. А для поиска проблемы он совершенно необходим.

Какие варианты я пробовал:

- в HTML-версию добавлял `<p data-order-id="...">` - веб-интерфейсы  gmail, и MS OWA это все вырезает, а при пересылке тем более. Просить прислать "бинарный оригинал письма" очень затруднительно.
- > `Добавляйте X- заголовки в письмо X-заголовки` - отличный вариант, но причина та же, мне письмо пересылают, все заголовки теряются

Особенности: Microsoft Exchange Server используется как шлюз при отправке писем. Я работаю в Outlook и MS OWA.

Какие есть еще варианты такой "стеганографии" в email? Также подойдет любой другой способ, главное что первичный источник данных - письмо.

Фантазирую: сохранять все исходящие письма, чтобы искать по ним, но этот вариант мне не нравится по многим причинам.

Comment: Добавляйте X- заголовки в письмо

Comment: как на счет картинки 1x1, с несуществующим адресом, где будет вся нужная инфа? Почтовики вряд ли такое вырежут

Comment: Хороший вариант, сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> в HTML-версию добавлял  - веб-интерфейсы gmail,
>   и MS OWA это все вырезает, а при пересылке тем более.

Если у вас есть доступ к `html`, то тогда просто добавляйте маленькую картинку ( можно даже прозрачную, но не факт что альфа канал поддерживается всеми почтовиками ) с адресом

```
http://unregistred-site.su?prop=val&prop2=val
```

В таком случае, вырезать картинку почтовик не станет и отобразит ее, но так как размеры `1x1px`, этого никто не заметит

Такая фишка с картинкой очень популярна. Работает даже если отключить `js`, так как браузер все равно отправит запрос на сервер. Вроде бы Яндекс делает так, для отправки статистики, если `js` отключен

Comment: Добавил, но картинка 1x1 реально существует. В чем подвох `главное, что бы адрес был не настоящим`?

Comment: @TotalPusher а какой адрес указали?

Comment: Можете указать и настоящий адрес, где лежит картинка. Тогда она будет загружаться, что при большой картинке может занять время и как-то повлиять ( возможно ) на размеры письма, время его загрузки. Но если вас это не беспокоит, то закрывайте глаза на это.

Comment: Однопиксельная прозрачная гифка весит сотню байт, по-моему вполне можно и реальную картинку (если никто не вырежет)

Comment: Спасибо, проверил, при пересылке на OWA все остается. На gmail - вырезается. Но я использую OWA, поэтому подходит. Хочу присудить вознаграждение, но пишет что через 18 часов. А я в отпуск. Надеюсь что получится зайти и нажать кнопку до конца конкурса.

Comment: @TotalPusher, **вам не нужно его награждать лично**. Согласно правилам награда присуждается **в полном объёме** в конце конкурса тому ответу, который **помечен зелёной галочкой**. К тому же он получит дополнительные баллы, т.к. его ответу будет больше внимания. _Приятного отпуска!_